# How to filter a multi-index stock timeseries dataframe for regression

Tags: python, filter, regression, stock

I'm really struggling with how to filter my dataframe to get ready for a regression analysis.

I have the multi-index dataframe "X_data" which contains all the independent/factor data for regression to predict stock returns. It is a multi-index dataframe with the 0 level index being the date and the 1 level index being the stock. Each column is a specific factor for the regression.

Here is the dataframe:

```
>>> X_data
                    dividendYield  priceToBook  ...  grossMargins  operatingMargins
public_date TICKER                              ...                                
2015-01-31  A              0.0106        2.334  ...         0.582             0.218
            AAPL           0.0160        5.178  ...         0.429             0.331
            ABBV           0.0325       20.700  ...         0.811             0.358
            ABT            0.0214        2.945  ...         0.590             0.211
            ACI            0.0108        0.181  ...         0.098             0.054
...                           ...          ...  ...           ...               ...
2022-12-31  ZBH            0.0075        2.093  ...         0.763             0.302
            ZBRA              NaN        4.840  ...         0.466             0.194
            ZM                NaN        2.891  ...         0.773             0.166
            ZS                NaN       37.417  ...         0.823            -0.221
            ZTS               NaN       13.886  ...         0.742             0.416

[41178 rows x 11 columns]
```

However, when I split the dataframe into training and test data based on date (using 6 months from the end of my data currently: 2022-06-30), there are more stocks in "X_train" than there are "X_test" because some stocks do not have recent data:

```
>>> len(X_train.index.get_level_values(1).unique())
480
>>> len(X_test.index.get_level_values(1).unique())
475
```

I want to remove any stocks that do not have sufficient data to split between test and training sets from X_data BEFORE I split the data into test and train dataframes.

My first approach was to remove any tickers that have more than 'n' number of consecutive NAs in a column. However, some stocks do not have data for every factor (column). For example, if a stock doesn't pay dividends, it won't have valid data in the "dividendYield" column but may have valid data in other columns that is usable, therefore I want to keep this stock. I maybe need at least 3 columns/factors that has continuous valid data for this approach.

My questions:

1. How would I implement the above approach?
2. Is there a better (more efficient/robust/etc.) approach that would remove the stocks that do not have sufficient data for regression?

I already tried filtering the X_test dataframe by the tickers in X_train dataframe. However, this brings the total number of tickers from 480 to 468 (not 475 as X_test has):

```
>>>X_train_clean = X_train[X_train.index.get_level_values(1).isin(list(X_test.index.get_level_values(1).unique()))].index.get_level_values(1).unique()

>>>len(X_train_clean)
468

>>> len(X_test.index.get_level_values(1).unique())
475
```

Why would this code filter more stocks than are in X_test??

Thank you in advance for your time responding to my question.